# Preventing multiple executions of observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a screen which needs to present some constantly changing data from an api. On the observable of my api call, i use repeatWhen() to implement the polling. Also, when i detect certain value changes on the incoming data, i need to do an additional api call. My current implementation works like this:

```
    let queueStatusObservable = this.enumService.getOptions('WorkQueueStatus');
    let queueItemObservable = this.enumService.getOptions('WorkItemStatus');

    // retrieve status every 3000ms
    let summaryObservable = this.service
        .getSummary(this.id)
        .repeatWhen(completed => completed.delay(3000));

    this.summaryModel$ = Observable.combineLatest(queueStatusObservable, queueItemObservable, summaryObservable)
        .map(results => {
            let workQueueStatusList = results[0];
            let workItemStatusList = results[1];
            let summary = results[2].status > -1 ? results[2] : null // convert empty {} object to null;

            let model = {
                workQueueStatusList: workQueueStatusList,
                workItemStatusList: workItemStatusList,
                summary: summary
            };

            return model;
        });

    // fetch validationmessages every time the count changes
    this.validationMessages$ = Observable.merge(
        summaryObservable.first((value, index) => value.statusCount['Invalid'] > 0),
        summaryObservable.pairwise().filter((value, index) => value[0].statusCount['Invalid'] != value[1].statusCount['Invalid'])
    ).flatMap(i => me.service.getMessages());

    // fetch errors every time the count changes
    this.errorMessages$ = Observable.merge(
        summaryObservable.first((value, index) => value.statusCount['Error'] > 0),
        summaryObservable.pairwise().filter((value, index) => value[0].statusCount['Error'] != value[1].statusCount['Error'])
    ).flatMap(i => me.service.getErrors());
```

There are no subscribe() calls on the observables, because those happen in my angular templates using the async pipe, like so:

```
    <div *ngIf="summaryModel$|async; let summaryModel">
```

I expected that i would get one api call every 3 seconds, and that all statements working on the summaryObservable would simply be triggered by this api call response.

It does not seem to work that way. When i open the network tab in chrome, i see that i get 4 api calls every 3 seconds. Is this how rxjs is supposed to work, or am i using rxjs in the wrong way?

***The solution i ended up with is:***

```
let summaryObservable = this.service
    .getSummary(this.id)
    .repeatWhen(completed => completed.delay(3000))
    .shareReplay();
```

Using the share methods, i dont need to manage connecting/deconnecting myself, and the shareReplay makes sure that every value can be requested multiple times.

Comment: So you have multiple `summaryModel$|async` in your template?

Comment: To start, if it's in the same template you might use the as syntax. Like `*ngIf="obs$ | async as obs"` and then just work on obs with one subscription. Also, you might want to search how to use `share` operator from rxjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the same `summaryObservable` 5 different times.  2 of them are single-use only `first` calls.  that would leave you with 3 different uses in general.

When you want to reuse the same observable multiple times, you need to use something like `publish` to "share" a single subscription of the observable with all the uses.

Try something like this:

```
let summaryObservable = this.service
  .getSummary(this.id)
  .repeatWhen(completed => completed.delay(3000))
  .publish(); // creates a ConnectableObservable

// ...
// all the rest of your code goes here
// ...

// Finally "connect" the observable to start the polling
// that will be shared by all the other usages
this.summaryConnection = summaryObservable.connect()
```

And make sure you define `ngOnDestroy` to stop the polling when your component is destroyed:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.summaryConnection.unsubscribe(); // .dispose() if using older version of RXJS
}
```

Comment: I have a condition like this:

      map(counter => counter + 1),
      startWith(0),
      map(counter => ({counter})),
      takeUntil(this.stop$),
      repeatWhen(() => this.start$),
      publish()

But this doesn't work repeatWhen still starts multiple observables